# Still getting spam emails after installing reCaptcha v2 Checkbox

Tags: php, recaptcha, spam

I am using reCaptcha v2 ( Checkbox ) at form but still i am getting spam email.

Code that is i am using

in form page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
      'sitekey' : 'KEY'
    });
  };
</script>
```

in form to show recapth

```
<div class="form-group"><div id="g-recaptcha"></div></div>
```

and script file

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Here is server side code in php file

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={KEY}&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $arr = json_decode($response,true);
    if(isset($arr['success'])){
    
/* here i am sending email using SMTP */

}else { /* error */ }
}else { /* error */ }
```

Now what to do next to stop spam ?

Comment: what do you mean by "getting spam" ? Do you mean you are receiving spam which is incoming junk mails ? the recapcha only check wether your site is used by human and then your site should , according to your description, send email out. (outgoing mail)

Comment: No not getting in spam folder.... getting spam message

Answer (score 2):

`isset` means the property exists and not `null`. You should change your condition to:

```
isset($arr['success']) && $arr['success']
```

Comment: response have "success" if verified  otherwise error message.

Comment: @YogeshSaroya That's incorrect. Look at their [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-response). It says `"success": true|false,`